# 'Error HH606: The project cannot be compiled' when using multiple solc versions

Tags: compiler-errors, ethereum, solidity, hardhat

i am trying to compile 2 different contracts through hardhat, using 2 different compilers versions. I keep getting the error:

```
Error HH606: The project cannot be compiled, see reasons below.

The Solidity version pragma statement in these files doesn't match any of the configured compilers in your config. Change the pragma or configure additional compiler versions in your hardhat config.
```

My module.exports in hardhat-config.js looks like this:

```
module.exports = {
  solidity: {
    compilers: [
      {
        version: "0.4.18",
      },
      {
        version: "0.6.0",
        settings: {},
      },
    ],
  },
};
```

Inside the contracts the compilers are defined like this:

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.18;
```

and

```
pragma solidity ^0.6.0;
```

What am i doing wrong? Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Try defining the compiler versions in your smart_contract like this `pragma solidity >=0.4.18 <=0.6.0;`

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

This is What you can do,
Check change your contracts pragma to one choice lets take "pragma solidity ^0.6.0; though it is always advisable to use the most current as of this post we are at pragma solidity ^0.8.9;"

Then also change the solidity version in your hardhat.config.js to the same version you used in your solidity contracts and compile again.